# What is the Postgres's equivalent/closest lock of Microsoft SQL Server's IX (Intent Exclusive) lock?

Tags: postgresql, locking

In Microsoft SQL Server, the code below is used to get the IX (Intent Exclusive) lock:

```
SELECT request_mode FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID() AND resource_associated_entity_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.cars');
```

In PostgreSQL, `pg_locks` table is available to tell locks information. However, there are many types of `locktype`, which are:

> relation, extend, frozenid, page, tuple, transactionid, virtualxid, object, userlock, or advisory

Which types of `locktype` from `pg_locks` is equivalent to IX (Intent Exclusive) lock from Microsoft SQL Server?

If `locktype` is the wrong column to look at `pg_locks`, please advise which column in `pg_locks` should I use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take a step back and check what Intent Locks are made for.

Transaction locking for **MS-SQL server** is broadly explained here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-locking-and-row-versioning-guide

And for **PostgreSQL** it's broadly explained here
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html

MS-SQL server doc says:

> Intent locks are named intent locks because they are acquired before a
> lock at the lower level, and therefore signal intent to place locks at
> a lower level.
>
> Intent locks serve two purposes:
>
> To prevent other transactions from modifying the higher-level resource in a way that would invalidate the lock at the lower level.
> To improve the efficiency of the SQL Server Database Engine in detecting lock conflicts at the higher level of granularity.

There is **no equivalent** to intent locks in PostgreSQL. The IS, IX, SIX, IU, SIU, UIX lock modes have no equivalent because they refer to a concept that PostgreSQL doesn't have and seemingly doesn't need.

Comment: Hmm, sounds like they use double-checked locking which is considered an anti-pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking

Comment: @Daniel Vérité, if I use `FOR UPDATE` in a SELECT statement, which `locktype` in `pg_locks` can tell whether `FOR UPDATE` has been used? Please advise. Thanks

Comment: @hunterex: please ask this in a new specific question.

Comment: You won't see the row locks taken by `FOR UPDATE` in the lock table, because row locks are not kept in the shared lock table - they are stored on the row itself (no lock escalation!). If someone ran `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` on a table, you will see a `RowShare` lock on the relation in `pg_locks`. The locking systems of these two databases work quite differently.