# How to get pg_locks related to a specific database in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, locking

This question is related to my previous one [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282728/what-is-the-postgress-equivalent-closest-lock-of-microsoft-sql-servers-ix-int)

In SQL Server, I could get the lock type from a specific database using the code below:

```
SELECT request_mode FROM sys.dm_tran_locks WHERE resource_database_id = DB_ID() AND resource_associated_entity_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.cars');
```

In Postgres 11, how to filter the `pg_locks` result to a specific database like how SQL Server's `resource_database_id = DB_ID() AND resource_associated_entity_id = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.cars')` works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-locks.html) `pg_locks` contains a column `database` which you can join to the `pg_database` view:

```
select l.*
from pg_locks l
  join pg_database d on d.oid = l.database
where d.datname = current_database();
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is better or not than accepted answer but I've done it without `join`:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_locks WHERE database = (SELECT oid FROM pg_database WHERE datname = current_database())
```