# How to check for row lock level when FOR UPDATE is used in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, locking, row

Related to previous question [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/282728/what-is-the-postgress-equivalent-closest-lock-of-microsoft-sql-servers-ix-int/282731?noredirect=1#comment552821_282731)

From the pg_locks [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/view-pg-locks.html), row level lock information is not available when `FOR UPDATE` is used in a `SELECT` statement.

Is there any way to check for row level lock when `FOR UPDATE` is used in a `SELECT` statement?
If yes, how can I do so with Postgres 11?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Row locks are not permanently stored in the shared lock table, but on the row itself, so you cannot simply query for them.

To figure out which rows in a table are locked by concurrent transactions, you could run

```
SELECT id FROM mytable
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM mytable
                 FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED);
```